# mod_rewrite http to https ends up in loop

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, ssl, redirect-loop

I've got the problem that I want to redirect my HTTP requests to a HTTPS using a shared SSL certificate. For some stupid reason of my host I have to attach the SSL Port on the request url.
Basically I want to redirect this:

```
http://sub.domain.com
```

to

```
https://sub.domain.com:12345
```

my .htaccess looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}:12345%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]
```

By this results in a redirect loop. I have no idea why though. Is this maybe because I use a shared SSL certificate which is not made for the domain and therefore the RewriteCond is always off?

thanks in advance!

EDIT:

I've checked the response header and saw that the location field still points to the non https url. But if I use another domain (or even a subdomain) it works. So why doesn't work the redirect to the same domain?

Comment: Shouldn't it just be `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off`? That works fine for me. If that is still acting up it isn't an issue with your htaccess. What does your browsers console say? (If anything)

Comment: didn't change anything.
console: Failed to load resource: net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS
If I take a look on the response header the "Location:" is still "http://sub.domain.com"
No https and no port at the end. Very strange...

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your condition to:

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 12345
```

Comment: Also tried this. Of course with !12345. Didn't work either. Please check my edit of the original post.